# Issue Facing in calling oracle stored procedure using Simple JDBC call of jdbc template

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jdbctemplate

Actually I am stuck with quite a time now regarding the below issue.
Does anyone has implemented Oracle Stored procedure calling through Java, I have implemented but getting the below error.

```
Exception occured in startAxonProducerProcess()","stack_trace":"org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call POST_CYCLE_TFO_STAT_PKG.GET_CYCLE_EVNT_PAY_RECORDS(?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17068]; Invalid argument(s) in call; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:89)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1147)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:412)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:372)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:198)
    at  ...
```

My procedure syntax is:-

```sql
PROCEDURE get_cycle_evnt_pay_records (
      RESULT_AXON_TB       OUT AXON_PAYMENT_TAB_T,
      ERROR_INFO           OUT VARCHAR2,
      RESULT               OUT BOOLEAN,
      DEBUG_FLAG        IN OUT BOOLEAN);
```

`AXON_PAYMENT_TAB_T` is of type `TYPE AXON_PAYMENT_TAB_T IS TABLE OF AXON_PAYMENT_RECORDS_T;`

And my Java code is like below:-

```java
  SimpleJdbcCall call1 = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                    .withProcedureName(GET_CYCLE_EVENT_PAY_RECORDS_PROCEDURE)
                    .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("RESULT_AXON_TB", Types.STRUCT))
                    .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("ERROR_INFO", Types.VARCHAR))
                    .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("RESULT", Types.BOOLEAN))
                    .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("DEBUG_FLAG", Types.BOOLEAN))
                    .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("DEBUG_FLAG", Types.BOOLEAN));
                  
            SqlParameterSource in1 = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                    .addValue("DEBUG_FLAG", true);
            
            Map<String, Object> result1 = call1.execute(in1);
```

Can anyone share any pointers on this, regarding the issue, it will be really helpful.

Comment: Please format your code as code, with four backticks (````) before and after the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would give up on using Spring JDBC and a `JdbcTemplate` to call this stored procedure, and just use plain JDBC.

The problem isn't so much the table-of-object type, but the `OUT BOOLEAN` parameters.  The `BOOLEAN` type isn't supported by JDBC so we have to work around it, and these workarounds don't fit easily into Spring JDBC.

I would use the following code instead:

```
    String plsql =
            "DECLARE\n" +
            "  l_debug_flag     BOOLEAN;\n" +
            "  l_result         BOOLEAN;\n" +
            "BEGIN\n" +
            "  l_debug_flag := sys.diutil.int_to_bool(?);\n" +
            "  package_name_here.get_cycle_evnt_pay_records(?, ?, l_result, l_debug_flag);\n" +
            "  ? := sys.diutil.bool_to_int(l_result);\n" +
            "  ? := sys.diutil.bool_to_int(l_debug_flag);\n" +
            "END;";

    try (Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()) {
        Map<String, Class<?>> typeMap = connection.getTypeMap();
        typeMap.put("AXON_PAYMENT_RECORDS_T", AxonPaymentRecords.class);
        connection.setTypeMap(typeMap);
        try (CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(plsql)) {
            statement.setInt(1, 1); // The second 1 here corresponds to the 'true' value you set for DEBUG_FLAG
            statement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY, "AXON_PAYMENT_TAB_T");
            statement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
            statement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.INTEGER);
            statement.registerOutParameter(5, Types.INTEGER);
            statement.execute();

            // Elements of this array should be AxonPaymentRecords instances.
            Object[] array = (Object[]) statement.getArray(2).getArray();

            String errorInfo = statement.getString(3);
            boolean result = (statement.getInt(4) == 1);
            boolean debugFlagOut = (statement.getInt(5) == 1);
            
            // do something with these values...
        }
    }
```

This uses two functions in the built-in `DIUTIL` package that convert between booleans and numbers, converting between `TRUE`/`FALSE`/`NULL` and `1`/`0`/`NULL` in the obvious way.  We can't call into JDBC with boolean values, so we pass integer values in and out, and convert between boolean and integer values on either side of JDBC.

You will need to write a Java class that represents your `AXON_PAYMENT_RECORDS_T` type, and it will need to implement [`SQLData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLData.html).  In the code above I named it `AxonPaymentRecords`.  You will need to implement the `getSQLTypeName` and `readSQL` methods of `SQLData`, but unless you are planning on calling any stored procedures with parameters of type `AXON_PAYMENT_RECORDS_T` then you can probably implement `writeSQL` to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` as you won't need to call it.

There are various places that Oracle type names appear: once when adding to the type map, once when registering the table-valued output parameter and once in the implementation of `SQLData` that I mentioned above.  You may need to qualify these type names with the schema owner, and also the package name if they are declared within a package.  (I am guessing they are declared within a package: in your code you don't include `CREATE OR REPLACE` in the definition of the type, and the appearance of `RECORD` within `AXON_PAYMENT_RECORDS_T` leads me to suspect that this type is a `RECORD` within a package, rather than an `OBJECT` declared outside a package.)  Similarly, you may also need to qualify the name of the stored procedure with schema owner and/or package name.

Note that if you are using Oracle 11g or older you won't be able to use types declared within a package.  I'm using Oracle 18c XE and I got this code working, although I had to make up the definition of the type `AXON_PAYMENT_RECORDS_T` and the associated Java class.

Comment: Hi Luke,
Thanks a lot. Thank you very much. Your suggested approach worked. Thanks for helping me out.